# ICommand Execute() Task.ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

In the `Execute()` of a class that implements `ICommand` in a WPF application, I have an external call to a method which returns a `Task`

ICommand Class:

```
public static void Execute(object parameter)
{
    Cancel(arg1, arg2);
}

private static void Cancel(IList<object> arg1, object arg2)
{

    Task<object> cancelTask = service.AmendAsync
    (
        CancelTokenSource.Token, 
        object arg2
    );

    ProcessCancellingResponse(arg1, arg2);
}

private static void ProcessCancellingResponse(IList<object> arg1, Task<object> cancelTask)
{
    cancelTask.ContinueWith
    (
        task =>
        {
            Update(task.Result.Response);
        },
        CancelTokenSource.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
}
```

Service Class:

```
public Task<object> AmendAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, object arg1)
{
    return Task<object>.Factory.StartNew
    (
        () =>
        {
            ...
        },
        cancellationToken,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default
    );
}
```

My questions are

1. what thread invokes the ICommend Execute() Is it the UI thread?
2. Will the `cancelTask.ContinueWith()` wait on the UI thread or on a background thread? i.e. if the `Task` takes a long time and it is waiting on the UI thread, the UI might freeze.

Comment: Following the answer from Dudi Keleti I've added more of the code which lead me to finding out that the underlying service call actually invokes a Task<object>.Factory.StartNew()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Domysee comment, I'll be clear here, the `Execute` is **always** run in the UI thread, but you can do in the callback whatever you want including run a background thread,

About the continuation, if you don't explicit tell him on with thread to continue, it will do its job on `TaskScheduler.Current`, else, it will continue on which scheduler you defined.

Anyway consider to use `async\await` with\out capturing to do a continuation

```
await Task.Run(() => ).ConfigureAwait(true);

await Task.Run(() => ).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Update**

According to question update,

Execute -> UI thread

Cancel => UI thread

AmendAsync => background thread

ContinueWith => UI thread (because you write `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`)

Comment: Assuming that there is not logic in between the Execute method and the Framework (like with RelayCommand or DelegateCommand base classes), it does not depend on the implementation. Execute can then start a new Task, but it will be called from the UI Thread.

Comment: @Domysee I don't assume anything ;) you are right but still it can be in any thread depending of implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. Arguably I should have been able to figure this out myself by debugging it properly, but I think by having to ask the question and the answers given has helped me figure it out. The code as I have it is isn't a problem because the AmendAsync does the actual work is on a background thread with the UI interactions taking place on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

> what thread invokes the ICommend Execute() Is it the UI thread?

Yes, it will always be on a UI thread.

> Will the cancelTask.ContinueWith() wait on the UI thread or on a background thread?

`ContinueWith` is just a regular method call. There's no magic. So break it down:

This:

```
private static void ProcessCancellingResponse(IList<object> arg1, Task<object> cancelTask)
{
  cancelTask.ContinueWith
  (
    task =>
    {
        Update(task.Result.Response);
    },
    CancelTokenSource.Token,
    TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
  );
}
```

is the same as this:

```
private static void ProcessCancellingResponse(IList<object> arg1, Task<object> cancelTask)
{
  Action<Task> continuation = task => { Update(Task.Result.Response); };
  var token = CancelTokenSource.Token;
  var options = TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion;
  var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
  cancelTask.ContinueWith(continuation, token, options, scheduler);
}
```

Since `ProcessCancellingResponse` is called on a UI thread, then `scheduler` will be a scheduler that executes its tasks on that UI thread. Thus, `continuation` will run on that UI thread.

---

On a side note, I see at least one mistake: `AttachedToParent` is almost certainly wrong. Promise tasks (asynchronous tasks) should almost never be attached tasks.

The implementations could be much cleaner, too:

```
private static async Task ProcessCancellingResponseAsync(IList<object> arg1, Task<object> cancelTask)
{
  var result = await cancelTask;
  Update(result.Response);
}

public object Amend(CancellationToken cancellationToken, object arg1)
{
  ...
}

private static void Cancel(IList<object> arg1, object arg2)
{
  Task<object> cancelTask = Task.Run(() => service.Amend
  (
    CancelTokenSource.Token, 
    object arg2
  );

  ProcessCancellingResponse(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why continuations shouldn't be run as `AttachedToParent` please?

Comment: `AttachedToParent` changes the semantics of the antecedent task. With Promise tasks, that changes what the task means. I.e., a "download" task is changed to mean a "download and process task". It's just surprising behavior for upstream code, and for this reason tasks intended for use with asynchronous code generally specify `DenyChildAttach` (which overrides `AttachedToParent`).

Comment: Isn't the `ContinueWith` attached to the `Cancel` by the fact it is invoked from the `Execute`? The continuation follows on from the method that invoked it rather than the async method which returns the task? Therefore `AttachedToParent` makes sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: I wasn't able to edit the previous comment so ignore that. Read this instead. Apologies but I'm answering on my phone now. Aren't the `ContinueWith` called via the `Cancel` which in turn is invoked by the `Execute` all executed on the UI thread? The continuation follows on from the method that invoked it rather than the async method which returns the task. Therefore `AttachedToParent` makes sense as I understand things. Invocation and continuation should be on the same thread. The only thing on another thread is the async task. Am I missing something?

Comment: `AttachedToParent` doesn't have anything to do with what thread it executes on. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

1. ICommand Execute() when called directly from UI runs on Main thread (UI thread).
2. It will depend where code is. If it is directly inside the Execute it will run on main thread as well because you are specifying the scheduler to be `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.